# How to change the login page for SecureSocial?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, securesocial

In [Installation](http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html) of SecureSocial, it said we need to add the following routes:

```
# Login page
GET     /login                      securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login
GET     /logout                     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.logout
```

But the action here is login/logout which is packaged by SecureSocial and we can't change it. How could we tell play which view to display for login page?

e.g type action of is like the following

```
  def index = Action {
    Ok(html.index(helloForm))
  }
```

That action will display a view page `helloForm.html`, however I can't find a way to change one for `securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login`. Please advice.

Comment: http://securesocial.ws/guide/views-customization.html Paragraph "Customizing Secure Social Templates"

Answer (score 1):

Securesocial view customization can be done by implementation of *TemplatesPlugin* located in *securesocial.controllers* package.

The method that you are looking for is called *getLoginPage()*.

```
class AuthTemplatesPlugin(application: play.Application) extends TemplatesPlugin {

  override def getLoginPage[A](implicit request: Request[A], form: Form[(String, String)], msg: Option[String] = None): Html = {
    views.html.myCustomLoginPage(form, msg)
  }

  //rest methods omitted
}
```

Don't forget about placing correct login form fields in your own view. I suggest checking default login page implementation as an example. It can be found in a public repository:

https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/views/login.scala.html

You also have to register your *TemplatesPlugin* implementation in a *play.plugins* file in a *conf* directory.

```
10000:models.auth.AuthTemplatesPlugin
```

An order number is just an example. To learn more about plugins in Play Framework go to documentation.

With a custom *TemplatesPlugin* it is possible to change other default securesocial views and mail templates. Full description is located here:

http://securesocial.ws/guide/views-customization.html